# Can't kick off the function which contains reference to another contract's function

Tags: solidity, erc-20, staking

I'm trying to test function (stake) which contains reference to another contract function (transferFrom). But when I test it I have a mistake. But MyToken has deployed and has address to hardhat network.

Here is a contract

```
import "./MyToken.sol";

contract Staking {
    MyToken public myToken;

    function stake(uint256 _value) public {
        myToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _value);
    }
}
```

Here is a test

```
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { assert } from "console";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { MyToken, MyToken__factory, Staking, Staking__factory } from "../typechain";
// import { MyToken, MyToken__factory } from "../typechain";

describe("MyToken", function () {
  let staking: Staking;
  let myToken: MyToken;
  let bob: SignerWithAddress,
    alice: SignerWithAddress;

  before(async () => {
    [bob, alice] = await ethers.getSigners();
  })

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const MyToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyToken") as MyToken__factory;
    myToken = await MyToken.deploy() as MyToken;
    await myToken.deployed();

    const Staking = await ethers.getContractFactory("Staking") as Staking__factory;
    staking = await Staking.deploy() as Staking;
    await staking.deployed();
  })

  **it("staking", async function () {
    const value = 100;
      await staking.stake(value);
  })**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `Staking` only looks as you shared in the question then you are not setting the address of `myToken`. You need to explicitly set the address either in the constructor or with the definition.

For example:

```js
import "./MyToken.sol";

contract Staking {
    MyToken public myToken;

    constructor(address token) {
      myToken = token;
    }

    function stake(uint256 _value) public {
        myToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _value);
    }
}
```

In your test you need to then pass the address of `myToken` to the `Staking.deploy` function:

```js
staking = await Staking.deploy(myToken.address) as Staking;
```

One way to debug this is to check in your test that `myToken` is initialized correctly:

```js
expect(await staking.myToken()).to.be.eq(myToken.address)
```